# Why am I getting error the instantiation line?

Tags: java

I am getting an error on the last line of the `main` method. Any idea why?

```java
public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] x = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0,};
    double[] y = {0.1666666667, 0.7142857143, 0.4285714286, 0.5714285714, 0.75, 0.4285714286, 0.8571428571, 1.0, 1.0, 0.2857142857, 0.5714285714, .05};
    LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression(double[] x, double[] y); // error
  };
}
```

Comment: Don't put the data types when you call a method or a constructor.  Delete `double[]` from this line.

Comment: Please improve the code formatting and add the error message you get to the question.

Comment: You have an extra `,` in your `double[] x` before the `}`

Comment: I think you mean `LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression(x, y);`

Answer (score 0):

You have the following errors in your program-

1. `LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression(double[] x, double[] y); // error };`
    Remove the extra semicolon as that will give you an error
2. `double[] x, double[] y`no need of writing that data type, only the variable is sufficient i.e. `LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression(x,y);`